# scipy.interpolate.rbf messes up interpolation for large z

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Can someone tell me what the limitations of .Rbf are? I have quite large z values but also when scaling them down I get weirdly random values for a non integer grid. When using a integer grid it seems to work alright...

```
import scipy.interpolate as sci
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(-1.4,-1.25641026,3)
y=np.linspace(-30,-23.68421052,5)
afd=np.array([[67012.37999509, 65416.76027155, 59893.18041826],[52767.97720273, 56538.82517715, 54604.71202974],[50725.8556277 , 42643.22600322, 44000.07955214],[42121.84799917, 39075.56307817, 39949.93033376],[31695.19321716, 41350.21431499, 32807.28556624]])
A,B=np.meshgrid(x,y)
x1=A.ravel()
x2=B.ravel()
z=afd.ravel()
tck = sci.Rbf(x1, x2, z, smooth=0)

xnew=np.linspace(-1.4,-1.25641026,3)
ynew=np.linspace(-30,-23.68421052,1*5) #double grid density
Anew,Bnew=np.meshgrid(xnew,ynew)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolor(Anew,Bnew,tck(Anew,Bnew))
print(tck(Anew,Bnew))
plt.subplot(122)
xnew=np.linspace(-1.4,-1.25641026,2*3-1)
ynew=np.linspace(-30,-23.68421052,2*5-1) #double grid density
Anew,Bnew=np.meshgrid(xnew,ynew)
plt.pcolor(Anew,Bnew,tck(Anew,Bnew))
print(tck(Anew,Bnew))
```

Comment: what is your p and q? also what is your function `symmetrize`? You should show the exact example of what weird values you get and under what conditions.[Show a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yes, you're right of course, I edited it! can you see the two results? That doesn't seem like correct interpolation does it?